# Calculate ArcTan in AceGen

Tags: trigonometry, acegen

I am working on a material model `SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"]` in AceGen and want to use command ToSphericalCoordinates for  but AceGen is always warning me:

`WARNING:The use of functions: ArcTan is potentially unsafe!!Plese consider using the AceGen alternative (e.g. Abs -> SMSAbs) See also: Auxiliary Variables`

The result is correct, but I want to write a code as it should be (no warnings). Then I went to manual calculation of transformation to spherical coordinates, but I need to use ArcTan and ArcCos. Again I get the same warnings. How to use the ArcCos and ArcTan appropriately?

I tried:

`th=ArcTan[SMSFreeze[y/x, "Code" -> True]]`

`SMSFreeze[th, ArcTan[y/x]]`

but this is not working - same warnings appear.

Comment: Have you considered using the AceGen alternative? The error itself tells you an example of how to go from the built-in to the alternative...

Comment: Thanks @CATrevillian for your feedback. I can't find trigonometric functions in AceGen list of alternatives. In help in says: For all other cases we can wrap critical function with the general unique signature function SMSFreeze[exp,"Code"->True]. But it seems I dont know how to use this correctly.

Comment: Have you tried something like `SMSArcTan`? That would follow precisely the example that they give for `Abs` to `SMSAbs`. You might consider contacting the developer about this issue, also.

Comment: The Warning is noting to worry about in your case, it is only important when you are at the limit of definition range of function, e.g. when you evaluate \sqrt(x), 1/x,... where you calculate x=0 or ArcSin/Cos(x), where x= +- 1. Mathematically x is 0, but in some cases x is not 0, but a small negative value in range of -10^-16, this will give you indeterminate value, however ArcTan is defined in whole real domain thus there should be no problems! This will depend on your equations too, while \sqrt(a^2+b^2) will be always positive or 0, \sqrt(a-b) might not be, even if a==b, due to numerics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inverse trigonometric functions are part of standard set of utility functions. That includes SMSArcTang. Look in the help under General Utility functions. SMS variants of the inverse trigonometric functions are needed to prevent wrong heuristic simplifications when combined with trigonometric conterpart (e.g. ArcTan(Tan(x)) => SMSArcTan(Tan(x)) or Sqrt(x^2) => SMSSqrt(x^2)). Thus, it is always advisable to use them. Even when the range of values is not problematic! [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess I have some other issues with my Mathematica library, because I don't have those functions available. Searching for SMSArcTan or similar doesn't give any results. 

I forgot to mention that I use Mathematica v12.3 in case this matters.

Comment: Reinstall helped.